# Python script : gives no such file or directory

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, voice-recognition, raspberry-pi2, wolframalpha

I am trying to search a query using wolframalpha api, I have made the python script executable.

```
chmod +x qp.py
```

and running it

```
./qp.py
```

But then I get an error

> :No such file or directory

This is my script

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import wolframalpha
import sys
app_id='KYPE8J-6PY3KHRRUA'
client = wolframalpha.Client(app_id)
query = ' '.join(sys.argv[1:])
res = client.query(query)
if len(res.pods) > 0:
    texts = " "
    pod = res.pods[1]
    if pod.text:
        texts = pod.text
    else:
        texts = "I have no answer for that"
        texts = texts.encode('ascii', 'ignore')
        print texts
else:
    print "Sorry, I am not sure."
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if /usr/bin/env exists, and if python is in your path, the most likely problem I can think of is that the file was copied from a Windows system and has embedded CRs (carriage returns). you can get rid of them with GNU sed: `sed -i 's/\r//' qp.py`, but first copy it somewhere safe in case that doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks for the reply...really helped

Comment: the best way to say thank you is to click the 'accept' checkmark :^)